# How to display e specific property in a Neo4j node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I`m creating a graph in Neo4j, but is there a way to define which property of the node to be displayed, when I browse the nodes in Neo4j browser?

In my case for the node Flight I want the property FL_NUM to be displayed in the node, but it automatically shows another property: DIV_AirportLandings, as shown below.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM "file:///Flight_data/5may2018.csv" AS line
WITH DISTINCT line
MERGE (f:Flight { id: TOINT(line.`flight_id`)} )
SET f.FlightNum = line.FL_NUM
SET f.Distance = line.DISTANCE
SET f.Diverted = line.DIVERTED
SET f.Cancelled = line.CANCELLED
SET f.CRS_ElapsedTime = line.CRS_ELAPSED_TIME
SET f.Actual_ElapsedTime = line.ACTUAL_ELAPSED_TIME
SET f.DIV_AirportLandings = line.DIV_AIRPORT_LANDINGS
SET f.DIV_ReachedDest = line.DIV_REACHED_DEST
```

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the result pannel (just under the query), you have facet for labels.
Just click on the `Filght(25)` and then a bar will appears at the bottom of the frame where you can select the color, size and the property to display.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I tried it several times, but the property selection was kind of hidden :)